# HTML5 / JS - preProcess of uploaded html page and simulate pagebreaks

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a html-5 based report generator. I created a button to upload a [HTML] page containing multiple paragraphs and tables, which is continuous.

Now my task is to display the whole contents into separated a4-sized pages, just like in Microsoft Word.]

This is the sketch: >>>[LINK](http://imm.io/18w24)<<<

Here are part of my codes.

```
 function xx (){

    var fi = document.getElementById('fi').files[0];          

        reader.onload = function (e){            
            var reader = new FileReader();                     
            var inner ="";
            inner  += this.result;

            inn.innerHTML ="<center><div class='bg' id='0'><div id='testmain'>"+inner+"</div></div></center>";

        }

        reader.onerror = function (e){
            dd.innerHTML = "error<br>";
        }
        reader.readAsText(fi);
    }
```

After displaying the result of pages, users can click a specific part of the paper, just like a paragraph, then a pagebreak is created and the pages changes, the remaining content are pushed starting from top of next page.

Could you please give me some ideas about how to realize it?

Comment: Do you mean that you need to show where the pages will break, or do you want to tell the browser where to cut pages when printing?

Comment: to Salketer: both. Pagebreaks can be implemented in printing, and what i need to do is to DISPLAY the result in formatted divs and looks like real pages.

Comment: I once tried to do such a thing, back in html4. Here's the logic I was using. Create a div that has the exact size of your page CONTENT (after margins and all) put all your content in it and cycle through its direct children. If the current child's bottom is lower than his parent, take it and all the following children and put them in a new div CONTENT. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: to Salketer: Many thanks. And could you please tell me which functions in js can judge whether exceeded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using comments as chat to present my suggestion, here's my answer:

I once tried to do such a thing, back in html4. Here's the logic I was using. Create a div that has the exact size of your page CONTENT (after margins and all) put all your content in it and cycle through its direct children. If the current child's bottom is lower than his parent, take it and all the following children and put them in a new div CONTENT. Rinse and repeat.

For this, you will need to calculate the height of the container and cross-check it against the offset+height of the elements. My vanillaJS is a bit rusty as for browser specifics and all... So I will display the logic using jQuery but most of it can easily be made in pure JS. The code will assume that we have a div.page that has the right CSS to make it exactly the size of a content page, and that will not resize to content (overflow:hidden) and the document will contain one of those div with all the content of what should be in the pages...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $page = $('div.page');
    var newPage = true;//To track if we loop
    while(newPage){
        newPage = false;
        $page.children().each(function(){
            if($(this).offset().top+$(this).outerHeight() > $page.offset().top+$page.height()){
                $page = $('<div>').addClass('page').appendTo('body');
                $(this).nextAll().appendTo($page);
                $(this).prependTo($page);//Don't forget the element too.
                newPage = true;
            }

        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Not tested but the idea's there

Comment: Thank you very much for your help！ It's enough for me to get my task done!